# How can I post form checkbox data using simple php?

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

Hi I am new to PHP and decided to try and create a form for the website I'm creating. I managed to do this to go to my mail address apart from sending checkbox data  - if more than one checkbox is checked only the last checkbox checked is displayed in the posted email. Can anyone let me know how I can do this? 
Here is the form code in www.newsite0914.i4dsign.co.uk/contact.php:

```
<form id="contact_form2" name="contact_formB" method="post" action="post.php">
        .....
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="nestedTable2">
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                    Services interested in&quest;
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                    Website <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="web" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                    Logo <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="logo" style=" margin-right: 50px;" />
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    Stationery <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="stationery" />
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" align="right" >
                    Advert <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="advert"style=" margin-right: 50px;" />
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td valign="top" colspan="2">
                    Other <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="other" /> <textarea cols="25" rows="1" name="other" value="other"style="margin-left: 10px;"></textarea>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                ...
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                Security Task: 6 + 7 =
                <input name="security" size="2" />

                <input type="submit" value="Send your details" onClick="checkDetailsB()" style="margin-left: 20px;"  /> 

                <!--<input type="reset" value="Reset"  />-->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

Here is the post php script (www.newsite0914.i4dsign.co.uk/post.php):

```
$to = "julian@i4dsign.co.uk";
$subject = "New Contact Form Submission";
$message = "....\n\nService: $service[$i]\n\n....";

if ($security=="13"){
    mail($to,$subject,$message);    
    header("Location:contact.php?s=1");
}
else{
    header("Location:contact.php?s=2");
}
```

Thank you in advance. I hope someone can help.

Comment: It's very hard to say for sure, given that you've not included much of your PHP code. You're passing an array of services in `$_POST['service']`, but it looks like you're only adding one entry to `$message`. Where are you setting `$i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$to = "julian@i4dsign.co.uk";
$subject = "New Contact Form Submission";
$message = "\n\nService: " . implode(', ', $_POST['service']);
```